# C# List <T> as an argument in class

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a problem, maybe someone will help me what I'm doing wrong (or just maybe could you just tell me what can I search in the web?)

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Telephone { get; set; }
    public List<Adres> Adres { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {}
    public Student (string firstname, string lastname, int index, int telephone, List<Adres> adres)
    {
        FirstName = firstname;
        LastName = lastname;
        Index = index;
        Telephone = telephone;
        List<Adres> Adres = adres;
    }  
}
public class Adres
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public Adres()
    { }
    public Adres(string street, int code, string city)
    {
        Street = street;
        City = city;
        Code = code;
    }
}
```

And I have two new classes in my Main project file

```
Adres _adres = new Adres ("street", code, "town");
Student _student = new Student("name", "surname", index, phone, List<Adres> _adres);
```

And in my _student class (this one in the bottom), I don't know how to put the _adres as an argument in the student class... (because it's a List)

Anyone? Pls?

The errors are:

```
 Error  2   The best overloaded method match for 'BazyDanych.Student.Student(string, string, int, int, System.Collections.Generic.List<BazyDanych.Adres>)' has some invalid arguments   
Error   3   Argument 5: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BazyDanych.Adres>'   
Error   4   Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments   
Error   5   'BazyDanych.Adres' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Comment: You misspelled `Address`

Comment: Standard convention for local variable names is "address" (spelled correctly) and not "_address".
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `List<T>` instead, just like any other class:

```
new List<Address>(new[] { _address })
```

`List<T>` happens to have a constructor that takes a sequence of items to add to the list, which helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `_adres` is not a `List<Adres>`. It is only an `Adres`. You will need to add it to a list. Something like:

```
Adres _adres = new Adres ("street", code, "town");
var adresList = new List<Adres>();
adresList.Add(_adres);
Student _student = new Student("name", "surname", index, phone, adresList);
```